# How to put integer value in JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I need to display an integer onto `JLabel`, the following code does not work out well, even with `Integer.parse()`.

How do I rectify it?

```
JLabel lblTemp = new JLabel("");
lblTemp.setBounds(338, 26, 46, 14);
contentPane.add(lblTemp);

//store int value of item clicked @ JList
int temp = list.getSelectedIndex() + 1;
lblTemp.setText(temp);   // <- problem
```

Comment: 1) Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556). 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`String.valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28int%29) method :

> Returns the string representation of the int argument.

```
lblTemp.setText(String.valueOf(temp));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
lblTemp.setText(String.valueOf(temp));
```

Your temp is an integer but the type that the `setText(...)` method accepts is String. You need to convert first your integer to String.

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty solution for putting integers in places that expect strings is to do the following:

```
lblTemp.setText(temp + "");
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

setText() takes string as an argument. Use this line to code to convert int to string.

```
Integer.toString(number)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you use **Wrapper class Integer** instead of primitive type int then you can get **temp.toString()** method that automatically convert to string value

Answer (score 0):

You can Use String.valueOf() or Integer.toString() Methods

lblTemp.setText(String.valueOf(temp));

or

lblTemp.setText(Integer.toString(temp));